# Capital first word and let remaining in camel case

Tags: javascript

I have a string " HELLO-WORLD". I want to keep HELLO as "HELLO" in caps and WORLD as "World". Expected output is "HELLO-World"

Could any one please help me with it??

Right now  i m using camel Title case only using following code

```
const toTitleCase = (string) => {
return string.replace(/\w\S*/g, (text) => {
  return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1).toLowerCase()
  })
 }
```

Comment: Please go through your previous questions and select correct answers before asking new questions.

Comment: Please share your code :)

Comment: @Isetty Ravitejakumar please see the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
 String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, end, what) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + what + this.substring(end);
};

var str = 'HELLO-WORLD';
str.replaceBetween(str.indexOf('-')+2, str.length, (str.substr(str.indexOf('-')+2, str.length).toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: @ Ahmed Ali Thanks , but Second Word was all coming in small letter , i needed Second letter in camel Title Case..I did This and i was able to achieve-----> const toTitleCase = (str) => {
  String.prototype.replaceBetween = function(start, what) {
    return this.substring(0, start) + what.replace(/\w\S*/g, (text) => {
       return text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.substr(1).toLowerCase()}) ;
};

return str.replaceBetween(str.indexOf('-')+1, (str.substr(str.indexOf('-')+1, str.length)));
}